# Zimbra MX lookup for delivery instead of local delivery

Tags: zimbra

On Zimbra server, both **local** and **remote** domain is available.

I am using same domain on two servers and, when an e-mail is sent from zimbra server, I want to receive it on another server instead  of local one (zimbra).

How can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Bhairav,

You will need to configure a relay to do this.
Please see the following:

- [Zimbra Outgoing SMTP Authentication](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Outgoing_SMTP_Authentication).
- [Zimbra Per-Domain Relay](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Relay_per_Domain).